# React NextJS - How do I update variables declared in Parent component inside a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I was looking over [React: Reverse data Flow](https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react#step-5-add-inverse-data-flow), to update `foodObj`, `input` and `buttonClicked` declared in `Main.js` (Parent Component) using the child component `<SearchAndSuggestion>`. Here are the two files.

`my-app/app/page.js` (Parent File)-

```
'use client'
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import FoodList from "./today_page/list/page";
import NutritionTable from "./today_page/nutrition_table/page";
import SearchAndSuggestion from "./today_page/search_and_suggestions/page";

export default function Home() {

const [foodObj, setFoodObj] = useState({});
const [input, setInput] = useState("");
const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

const buttonF = (value) => {
    setButtonClicked(value)
}

const inputF = (value) => {
    setInput(value)
}

const foodObjF = (value) => {
    setFoodObj(value)
}


return (
    <main className="flex flex-row overflow:hidden items-center justify-between p-24">
        ...
    <div className='flex flex-col m-4 border-blue-600'>
        ...
        {/* right side upper half*/}
        <SearchAndSuggestion foodObjF={foodObjF} inputF = {inputF} buttonF ={buttonF}/>
        ...
    </div>

    <p>{foodObj + ", " + input + ", " + buttonClicked}</p>
</main>
)
}
```

`my-app/app/today_page/seaerch_and_suggestion/page.js` (Child Component) -

```
'use client'

import { useEffect } from "react"

const SearchAndSuggestion = ({foodObjF, inputF, buttonF}) => {

    let query = " "

    const updateObj = (obj, query) => {
        if(obj && typeof obj === 'object'){
            if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(query)){
                obj[query] = 1
            }else{
                obj[query]++
            }
        }
        return obj
    }

    const handleClick = () => {
        if(query != " "){
            inputF(query)
            foodObjF(prevObj => updateObj(prevObj, query))
            buttonF(true)
            query = " "
            document.getElementById('myInput').value = ''
        }else{
            console.log("Failed")
        }
    }

    return (
        // Search bar, button with suggestion box
        <div className='flex flex-col flex-wrap box-border bg-gray-500 rounded-2xl border-gray-950 border-r-blue-600'>
            <form className='flex flex-row'>
                <input
                    id = "myInput"
                    className='m-2 w-120 h-8 rounded-2xl'
                    onChange = {(e) => {
                        query = e.target.value
                    }}
                    />
                <button 
                    className='w-20 h-8 bg-white m-2 rounded-2xl'
                    type='button'
                    onClick = {() => handleClick}
                    >
                    Find
                </button>
            </form>

            <div className='box-border h-48 w-144 m-2 bg-gray-300 border-1 rounded-2xl bg-grey-200'>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchAndSuggestion
```

The problem is that whenever I enter something in the input made inside `<SearchAndSuggestion>`, it doesn't change `<p>{foodObj + ", " + input + ", " + buttonClicked}</p>` written in Parent component file. I am not sure where the problem exist. Could someone point it out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in the button's click handler, you're not calling the `handleClick` function, you're just returning it.

Should look like this:

```
...
<button 
    className='w-20 h-8 bg-white m-2 rounded-2xl'
    type='button'
    onClick={()=>handleClick()}
>
    Find
</button>
...
```

or better still pass is directly to the `onClick` handler:

```
...
<button 
    className='w-20 h-8 bg-white m-2 rounded-2xl'
    type='button'
    onClick={handleClick}
>
    Find
</button>
...
```

Secondly, you can't set a variable in react the way you did in the input's `onChange` handler.

You have to make `query` a state and make the input controlled.
Like so:

```
...
const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
...

...
<input
    id = "myInput"
    className='m-2 w-120 h-8 rounded-2xl'
    value={query}
    onChange = {(e) => {
        setQuery(e.target.value);
    }}
/>
...
```

Comment: @parth please take a look at my edited response.

Comment: 1) Earlier I had `onClick = {handleChange}` but it gave me Too many re-renders error. Changing it to `onClick = {() => handleChange}` avoided the mistake. I still didn't know how that change fixed the error. 

2) I realize that I am using reactJS, where I can only use react components.Why can't I use `query`, which is never used directly to render a component?

Comment: @ParthGupta 1) writing `onClick= {() => handleChange}` won't call the function. I'm curious what errors you got when you tried `onClick={handleChange}`, it could have derived from a larger issue with the code and not the passing of the function. However, you can still try `onClick={()=>handleClick()}`. 2) you can use `query` defined as a regular variable, you just can't use it to change the state of the component. Changing it this way won't cause the app to rerender (which is what you need), the way to make it rerender is to change the state, which is why I suggested defining it as a state.

Comment: Yeah you were correct. The error I was getting from`onClick= {() => handleChange}` was part of a larger issue that is not included in this code. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

You're first using a local variable and not state when you're changing `query`, so you will not get a re-render since react will only re-render a component when state(s) change. I think it may be best to understand controlled inputs in react (simply, you have to use state var as the value of the input and on the specific event, update that state).

In your case, you could send both the input (state) and the setState fn for that input.

```js
<input
 id = "myInput"
 className='m-2 w-120 h-8 rounded-2xl'
 value={input}
 onChange = {(e) => inputF(e.target.value)}
/>
```

seems like another commenter also mentioned it as well.

Comment: Changing it to `onChange = {(e) => inputF(e.target.value)}` gave me `Error: Too many re-renders.`

Comment: Oops never mind. I was getting the error due another component not mentioned here.